# Does Thor possess any powers without Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir

The inscription on Mjolnir says "Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor"; which is what exactly?

In other words, does Thor have any powers other than that given to him by wielding the hammer?